# Apache Commons Hex Encoding Error

Tags: java, hex, apache-commons-codec

I'm trying to use [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex](http://commons.apache.org/codec/xref/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) to encode and decode a String value:

e.g.:

```
Hex.encodeHex("10".getBytes()).toString();
```

However, this is not giving me a hexadecimal output, but outputs similar to this:

> [C@596d444a

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - the call to `encodeHex()` returns a char array (`char[]`) and you're just calling `toString` on that. Use the String(char[]) constructor instead:

```
new String(Hex.encodeHex("10".getBytes()))
```

(I would *strongly* encourage you not to use the parameterless `String.getBytes()` method, by the way, which uses the platform default encoding. It's a constant source of subtle errors.)

Answer (score 0):

As per the link you have given: `public static char[] encodeHex(byte[] data)` return `@return A char[] containing hexadecimal characters`. Hence the output is right. Create a string using the char array.